# How to convert the elastic search json query into equivalent Java API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, java-8, elastic-stack

I have the below elastic search JSON Query and want to convert it into equivalent Java API. How can I convert this with Elastic Search Java API?

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "min": {
      "min": {
        "field": "<The date>"
      }
    },
    "max":{
      "max": {
        "field": "<The date>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I had tried using **MaxAggregationBuilder** and **MinAggregationBuilder**, but in that case I had to do two seperate API calls , one for Max and the another one for Min.

```
MaxAggregationBuilder=AggregationBuilders.max("max").field("date");
MinAggregationBuilder=AggregationBuilders.max("min").field("date");
```

How can I do this in one API call itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two statements are not two **API calls**, they are just call statements of a builder that builds up the query that you're going to send in one API call:

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
// query part
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()); 

// aggregation part
searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(AggregationBuilders.max("max").field("date"));
searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(AggregationBuilders.max("min").field("date"));

// request part
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(); 
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder); 

// API call
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```